# Can't access my kubernetes services even after exposing it with LoadBalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, load-balancing, kubernetes

I have created the replication controller in Kubernetes with the following configuration:

```
{
   "kind":"ReplicationController",
   "apiVersion":"v1",
   "metadata":{
      "name":"guestbook",
      "labels":{
         "app":"guestbook"
      }
   },
   "spec":{
      "replicas":1,
      "selector":{
         "app":"guestbook"
      },
      "template":{
         "metadata":{
            "labels":{
               "app":"guestbook"
            }
         },
         "spec":{
            "containers":[
               {
                  "name":"guestbook",
                  "image":"username/fsharp-microservice:v1",
                  "ports":[
                     {
                        "name":"http-server",
                        "containerPort":3000
                     }
                  ],
                  "command": ["fsharpi", "/home/SuaveServer.fsx"]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The code of the service that is running on the port 3000 is basically this:

```
#r "Suave.dll"
#r "Mono.Posix.dll"
open Suave
open Suave.Http
open Suave.Successful
open System
open System.Net
open System.Threading
open System.Diagnostics
open Mono.Unix
open Mono.Unix.Native

let app = OK "PONG"

let port = 3000us
let config =
  { defaultConfig with
     bindings = [ HttpBinding.mk HTTP IPAddress.Loopback port ]
     bufferSize = 8192
     maxOps = 10000
  }

open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let cts = new CancellationTokenSource()
let listening, server = startWebServerAsync config app
Async.Start(server, cts.Token)

Console.WriteLine("Server should be started at this point")
Console.ReadLine()
```

After I created the service I can see the pod:

```
$kubectl create -f guestbook.json
replicationcontroller "guestbook" created
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                   READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
guestbook-0b9py        1/1       Running            0          32m
```

I want to access my web service and create the service with type=LoadBalancer that will expose the 3000 port with the following configuration:

```
{
   "kind":"Service",
   "apiVersion":"v1",
   "metadata":{
      "name":"guestbook",
      "labels":{
         "app":"guestbook"
      }
   },
   "spec":{
      "ports": [
         {
           "port":3000,
           "targetPort":"http-server"
         }
      ],
      "selector":{
         "app":"guestbook"
      },
      "type": "LoadBalancer"
   }
}
```

Here is the result:

```
$ kubectl create -f guestbook-service.json
service "guestbook" created
$ kubectl get services
NAME         CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
guestbook    10.0.82.40                 3000/TCP   7s
kubernetes   10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP    3h
$ kubectl describe services
Name:           guestbook
Namespace:      default
Labels:         app=guestbook
Selector:       app=guestbook
Type:           LoadBalancer
IP:         10.0.82.40
LoadBalancer Ingress:   a43eee4a008cf11e68f210a4fa30c03e-1918213320.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
Port:           <unset> 3000/TCP
NodePort:       <unset> 30877/TCP
Endpoints:      10.244.1.6:3000
Session Affinity:   None
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubobjectPath   Type        Reason          Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------   --------    ------          -------
  18s       18s     1   {service-controller }           Normal      CreatingLoadBalancer    Creating load balancer
  17s       17s     1   {service-controller }           Normal      CreatedLoadBalancer Created load balancer


Name:           kubernetes
Namespace:      default
Labels:         component=apiserver,provider=kubernetes
Selector:       <none>
Type:           ClusterIP
IP:         10.0.0.1
Port:           https   443/TCP
Endpoints:      172.20.0.9:443
Session Affinity:   None
No events.
```

The "External IP" column is empty

I have tried to access the service using "LoadBalancer Ingress" but DNS name can't be resolved.

If I check in the AWS console - load balancer is created (but in the details panel there is a message "0 of 2 instances in service" because of health-checks).

I have also tried to expose my RC using kubectl expose --type=Load-Balancer, but result is the same.

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you each the pod on its internal cluster IP on port 3000? Can you reach the service on its internal IP and port 3000? Is AWS configured to use port 3000 as well?

Comment: @TimoReimann AWS is all open in the settings of EC2 instances, I've checked the rules of the security groups. Will try the internal and cluster IPs in a bit

Comment: @Timoreimann No, can't reach it using the internal IP and cluster IP. AWS is configured to use the port, it's all open. What else might it be and why I can't reach anything?

Comment: @TimoReimann I can only access the service when I kubectl exec -ti name -- bash into the pod

Comment: Are you certain that the cluster IP is reachable? If you do this from your development machine and you have not set up routing accordingly, you will need to set up port-forwarding via `kubectl port-forward <pod-name> <local port>:<container port>` (where `<container port>` should be `3000` in your case) and then try to connect to the pod through `localhost:<local port>`.

Comment: @TimoReimann Will try. But why isn't it enough for me to just defile the service type=LoadBalancer in Kubernetes? It should be available via external IP, shouldn't it?

Comment: @TimoReimann yes, I can reach my pod now using localhost:3000 with port forwarding. But pod is the low level entity. What if I have a replication controller and a service to manage it? How can I make my service with type LoadBalancer accessible? Because if I can reach my pod with port forwarding, that means that cluster can be accessible from external world. What is the way for me to access it using External IP instead of "localhost" way? The command "kubectl expose rc my-controller --port=3000 --target-port=3000 --name=my-service --type=LoadBalancer" doesn't seem to work. Do I miss any steps?

Comment: Validating that we can talk to the pod was only to isolate the problem. You're absolutely right that exposing it via the load balancer is the way to go to make it accessible properly.

Comment: Let's see if we can reach the service next: since load balancer-level exposure requires cloud provider support which could possibly be broken, could you please delete the service, recreate it with a NodePort, and see if you can reach it via the exposed node port? Please make sure your firewall isn't blocking access on that port.

Comment: I just realized that every LoadBalancer-typed service should already expose a NodePort, so you shouldn't need to recreate the service.

Comment: @TimoReimann if I want to try my replication controller with the NodePort service, is this configuration correct to try with - http://pastebin.com/YLfT6ZhC?

Comment: @TimoReimann I tried same steps that i do, on Google Cloud - External IP shows up, but still can't reach the service :(

Comment: @TimoReimann Hey friend, I made it work. The problem was in the actual microservice. 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 in the code of the web server.

Comment: Ah, glad to hear. Didn't look too close at the application code, unfortunately. :-)

Comment: Would you post an answer to your question yourself so that future generations will know?

Comment: @TimoReimann yes, will do that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the error.

The thing was in the actual service. It needs to be listening on 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 or localhost. That way it will listen on every available network interface. More details on the difference between 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1: https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1